# Don't display graphite metrics without data in the time range

Tags: graphite

I have a cluster of AWS servers that I track statistics using Graphite. The servers in the cluster change as new versions of software are deployed or as the cluster size grows or shrinks.

**For example**:

> **Metrics added yesterday**
>       servers.1.cpu
>       servers.2.cpu
>
> **Metrics added today**
>       servers.2.cpu
>       servers.3.cpu

When I view my data through Graphite I only want it to show me metrics for the servers that have data for the time period that I am querying. However, because I don't know what servers were available in the time period I specify `*` in the query and this results in all servers that have every existed in the cluster to be included in the series.

> **query last 15 minutes**:
>       servers.*.cpu
>   **Results in**:
>       servers.1.cpu
>       servers.2.cpu
>       servers.3.cpu

Is there a way to filter out the servers that don't have data from the series? So that in the above example I don't include metrics from `servers.1.cpu`. However, if my query time period was yesterday I would get `servers.1.cpu`, but not `servers.3.cpu`.

Comment: There is a related question here. How do you efficiently store metrics when the servers are changing all of the time. If you use the IP address of the server in the metric name you will have tons of sparse metrics as the servers rotate out. This seems like an extremely inefficient use of disk space.

Answer (score 1):

Graphite allocates all the space for a metric the first time it receives a single value. This results in a very inefficient representation for any system where the metrics are sparse. For example in a system where the servers are highly dynamic. I resolved on two possible solutions:

1. Use slot names for the metrics rather than the actual server identifiers (IPs). I really don't like this because it causes you to look up the server using the slot name before you can actually go to the server that generated the metrics.
2. Use InfluxDB instead. InfluxDB only stores the metrics that you actually provide and queries only return data if there actually is data to return. This results is a compact representation that only shows you data for the metrics that actually had data during the time span that is queries.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar problem with metrics sent via statsd to Graphite. In some cases I've been able to use [`currentAbove(0)`](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.currentAbove) to filter out series without "interesting" values; this was successful for values from the [collectd load plugin](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:Load).

Gauges are a particular problem, since once an AWS instance is terminated all gauge metrics from that instance will remain "stuck" at their last value.

Some ideas I had around this area:

- Use [CloudWatch Events](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/automatically-delete-terminated-instances-in-chef-server-with-aws-lambda-and-cloudwatch-events/) to set all gauges for terminated instances to 0; unfortunately Graphite's poor search api would make this a bit challenging
- Add [custom functions](https://github.com/brutasse/graphite-api/blob/master/docs/custom-functions.rst) to Graphite, eg it would be fairly easy to write a function to filter out a series where the first & last values were the same
- We're using Grafana so we could add a [scripted dashboard](http://docs.grafana.org/v1.9/reference/scripting/) where the script fetches the current AWS hostnames (from the Salt master, handwavey handwavey) & dynamically populates the series for the dashboard.

Developing the idea of filtering out constant series, `averageAbove(integral(nonNegativeDerivative(...)), 1)` seems like a good start but I can't work out how to display only the original series.

Comment: I would highly suggest you replace Graphite with InfluxDB. The functionality and performance are fantastic. Grafana support for influxDB is great. You can also skip Graphite if you are in AWS and just use Grafana's CloudWatch connector. The downside is that you pay a little for queries and you only get two weeks of data.